# How to separate your code from specific customer code?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I have the following design problem:

I have many lines of object oriented source code (C++) and our customers want specific changes to our code to fit their needs. Here a very simplified example:

```
void somefunction() {
    // do something
}
```

The function after I inserted the customer wishes:

```
void somefunction() {
    // do something
    setFlag(5000);
}
```

This looks not so bad, but we have many customers which want to set their own flag values on many different locations in the code. The code is getting more and more messy. How can I separate these customer code from my source code? Is there any design pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One strategy to deal with this is to pull the specifics "up" from this class to the "top", where it can be setup or configured properly.

What I mean is:

1. Get the concrete settings out of the class. Generalize, make it a parameter in the constructor, or make different subclasses or classes, etc.
2. Make all the other objects that depend on this depend on the interface only, so they don't know about these settings or options.
3. On the "top", in the `main()` method, or some builders or factories where everything is plugged together, there you can plug in the exact parameters or implementations you need for the specific customer.

I'm afraid there is no (correct) way around refactoring these classes to pull all of these specifics into one place.

There are workarounds, like getting configuration values at all of these places, or just creating different branches for the different versions, but these do not really scale, and will cause maintenance problems in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty general question, so the answer will be quite general. [You want your software to be open for extensions, but closed for modifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). There are many ways to achieve this with different degrees of openness, from simple ones like parameters to architecture-level frameworks and patterns. Many of the design patterns, e.g. [Template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) deal with these kinds of issues. Essentially, you provide hooks or placeholders in your code were you can plug-in custom behavior.

In modern C++, some of these patterns, or their implementation with explicit classes, are a bit dated and can be replaced with lambda functions instead. There are also numeruous examples in standard libraries, e.g the use of allocators in STL containers. The allocator let's you, as a customer of the STL, change the way memory is allocated and deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

To limit the uncontrolled writing of code, you should consider to expose to your customer a strong base class(in the form of interface or abstract class) with some(or all) methods closed to modification.
Then, every customer will extend the base class behaviour implementing or subclassing it. Briefly, in my thought, to every customer corresponds a subclass CustomerA, CustomerB, etc.. in this way you'll divide the code written by every customer.
In my opinion, the base class methods open to modification should be a very limited set or, better, none. The added behaviour should stay only in the added methods in the derived class, if possible; in this way, you'll avoid the uncontrolled modification of methods that mustn't be modified.